# C# .NET Dynamic TextBox from SQL Results

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, m

I'm not usually one for asking questions but I am interested to see different ideas. I have a webforms app which I am looking to dynamically populate textboxes based on the query results. Basically if I query the below:

```
SELECT Product_Field_ID, Product_ID, SortOrder, Name, Type FROM Product WHERE product_id = 100
```

I would get a results table as follows:
[image]

I would  add this to a datatable or IEnumerable interface and then iterate through a for each list dynamically creating the controls.

For the purpose of this question I would use something like the below:

```
            int a;
        for (a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            Label Label = new Label();
            Label.ID = "LabelFortxt" + dt.Rows[a]["Name"].ToString();

            TextBox Text = new TextBox();
            Text.ID = "txt" + dt.Rows[a]["Name"].ToString();

            //Placeholder on the aspx page
            PlaceHolderControls.Controls.Add(Label);
            PlaceHolderControls.Controls.Add(Text);
        }
```

My plan would be to then either populate the data if it is required or the user would complete the information before submitting it back to the database. For this I would use a stored procedure with the parameters added using the previous datatable which I would have kept active in the ViewState or Session. I am stuck with the below when it comes to adding the information back to the database:

```
            int a;
        for (a = 0; a < dt.Rows.Count; a++)
        {
            Control dynamiccontrolname = dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString(), "txt" + dynamiccontrolname.Text
        }
```

I recall being able to reference a control using a variable but I cannot work it out. Also before I really get started with this I would like to hear different opinions or better approaches hopefully even a good approach to receiving the data back to the database. (currently I am thinking to dynamically build the query using the params sent by the application.)

UPDATE: If it helps to further explain my requirement different product types require different data collecting and I cannot afford to hard code based on category or product type, so I intend to let the user specify the data fields when creating the product/category. This bit is done. As the user scans a product the data entry screen appears and the respective fields are dynamically created in the UI. I have all of this working. I now simply need to know how I can access the controls to either populate with any existing data or retrieve any entered data to then store back in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to add values to your command you have to use parameter name first and then the value:

```
cms.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourValueInQuery", dt.Rows[0]["Name"].ToString());
```

I would suggest to use `Add()` method so you could restrict user input by specifying type and length of the data. Or even better create a model class with properties `Product_Field_ID, Product_ID, SortOrder, Name, Type` and perform CRUD operations using Dapper.

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you for your help, I did rush to finish the question I would add the parameters to the stored procedure safely. My question was aimed more around the best way to dynamically create the controls and then to capture the inputted data from them again.